# site works on chrome but not on curl

Tags: ssl, curl

The error is this:

```
* Connected to www.****.com (213.74.254.54) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
```

Same URL opens just fine on chrome. I tried to copy as curl from chrome and run using curl too, same error. So maybe somehow chrome is more slack on the SSL negotiation. How can I make curl behave the same?

curl version:

```
curl --version
curl 7.80.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0) libcurl/7.80.0 OpenSSL/3.0.1 zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.1 (+libidn2/2.3.2)
Release-Date: 2021-11-10
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

Comment: The server does not support secure renegotiation - see [this SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=morhipo.com). This should be fixed on the server side. Unfortunately nothing is known about the server software and setup, so no help can be provided here.

Comment: This call seems to work on ubuntu but not on mac os.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem when trying to connect to `https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com`. When I'm doing tests directly from my local computer everything seems to work OK, however once I upload the code to the server and I try to execute from there, I get the same problem. Versions in local computer are `curl 7.86.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0) libcurl/7.86.0 LibreSSL/3.3.6` while in the server I have `curl 7.85.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.85.0 OpenSSL/3.0.8`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meta: this isn't really programming or development; I will delete if necessary but I think superuser would be suitable and have voted for that (but we'll see what others think). I can see equally good arguments for apple.SX or security.SX instead, but (AFAIK) those would require a mod.

While Steffen is correct the server is either badly out of date or misconfigured and should be fixed, OpenSSL below 3.0.0 (just last year) by default will connect to a non-RFC5746 server as long as the server does not actually *use* the unsafe 'legacy' (RFC5246 et pred) renegotiation.

Thus if you can get/use a curl using older OpenSSL it should just work. I'm not sure what the situation is for Mac on this, for example if brew or fink or similar has this available. Worst case, both OpenSSL and curl are opensource so you could build your own older versions -- and that *would* be ontopic for SO, but a fair bit of work.

Alternatively, as long as curl doesn't work to mess it up (which I wouldn't expect, but don't know for sure), OpenSSL 1.1.0 up can control this with runtime configuration:

1. Either edit your systemwide config file `openssl.cnf` in the directory identified by `openssl version -d` (affects all programs and processes) or create your own file anywhere suitable and point to it with environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF`. See the man page for config(5) on your system [or the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man5/config.html).
2. In the default section (beginning of the file to the first line wrapped in square brackets) add if not already present an item `openssl_conf = sect1` where sect1 is conventionally `openssl_init` but can be any section-name unique in the file.
3. Create sect1 if not already present, and add if not already present an item `ssl_conf = sect2` where sect2 is conventionally `ssl_configuration` but as above.
4. Create sect2 if not already present, and add if not already present an item `client = sect3` where sect3 is conventionally `client_tls_config` but as above.
5. Create sect3 if not already present, and add if not already present an item for `Options =` whose value is (or is a comma-separated list including) `UnsafeLegacyServerConnect`. See the man page for SSL_CONF_cmd(3) on your system [or the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_CONF_cmd.html#SUPPORTED-CONFIGURATION-FILE-COMMANDS).

Comment: This call seems to work on ubuntu but not on mac os. Something with underlying TLS libraries probably.

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same issues after upgrading to ubutun22 and openssl 3.0.2.

Using the steps by dave_thompson_085 with `client` pointing to a sect with the new option did not work for me.  But adding the `Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation` line to the `system_default_sect` at the bottom of the file did:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_configuration

[ssl_configuration]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=2
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
```

Comment: The following almost works as a command option for curl: `echo -e "openssl_conf = openssl_init\n[openssl_init]\nssl_conf = ssl_sect\n[ssl_sect]\nsystem_default = system_default_sect\n[system_default_sect]\nOptions = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation" | OPENSSL_CONF=/dev/stdin curl https://old-host/`